# Mixing XmlValue and XmlElement Marshalling (Generating XML)

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

I was scouring around SO trying to figure out this issue I was having while generating xml using JaxB. I found some solutions for unmarshalling, but trying to apply these solutions the other way around did not end up so well for me.

I have a situation where I have a root element that may have a value OR more elements in it (depending on some logic).

So it could end up like this:

```
<custom-attribute>
    <value>Some Value</value>
    <value>Some Other Value</value>
</custom-attribute>
```

or

```
<custom-attribute>Some Value</custom-attribute>
```

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAttribute {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute-id")
    private String attribute_id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private List<ValueElement> valueList;
}
```

With the ValueElement just being a class with an @XmlValue string in it. I get the complaint that

```
unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

If I try to use @XmlMixed on the String value;

And as is it complains that something cannot have both an element and value.

Is there any elegant solution to this without creating another class just to handle a list of elements?